# Advanced Math Mode Customization in XeLaTeX

Tags: math-mode, fonts, xetex, fontspec

**Observation**

If you have used [MathType](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathType) in Word, you know well that we can customize the font of the equations -- not only change the overall font, but also change the font of brackets, numbers, symbols (e.g. `+` or `≈`), variables, Greek letters, or functions (e.g. `exp` or `sin`), like this:

[image]
[image]

**What I want**

I am using XeLaTeX for my school report. However, the math font doesn't suit the whole document much.

I know that I can change the math font in XeLaTeX using `\setmathfont`. However, it applies for all, not just the symbols or numbers... (of course). I want to know if I can change the font of the symbols only, for instance, and how I can do it.

May you help me? Thank you in advance.

*Bonus:* It will be far better, if you can help me customize more than that, for example the color of the functions. It will help me a lot!

**Any help will be very highly appreciated!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for the `unicode-math` package explains how to use a specific math font only for certain Unicode ranges of glyphs. For example,

```
\setmathfont{Linux Libertine O}[range=bfsfit/{greek,Greek}]
```

will change the font used for lowercase and uppercase Greek symbols in math mode. You can also select the font used for specific math symbols such as `\int`.